# Log message in perl every 90 seconds in the parent process as long as the child process still runs

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I just passed over from php to perl due to my company's request so even if this may be a silly question is kind of nerve wreaking right now.

I have one little perl script deployed on a server through a debian package. I have this all figured out so that's all cool.

Now this script is called from another server through an SSH connection and the script logs back to that server all its actions. I use Log::Log4perl for that.

One of the tasks takes a very long time and also runs some other scripts in the process. The ssh connection has a set timeout of 5 minutes unless I log something back. So I figured out I would create a child process to run the task and let the parent process log back every 90 (or whatever) seconds. My issue is that **I don't want to use sleep** because if the task is finished sooner it will mess up the log.
I have also tried using Time, Time::HiRes and alarm, but they all mess up my log one way or another.

This is my code:

```
    $log->info("uid $uid: calling the configure script for operation $mode,on $dst_path");

    my $pid   = fork();
    die "Could not fork\n" if not defined $pid;

    if ( $pid == 0 ) {
        configure( $script_dir, $mode, $node, $uid, $gid); # this also uses a parallel process in its execution, but we don't have a non blocking wait
    }
    while ( !waitpid( $pid, WNOHANG ) ) {
        sleep(90);
        if ( !$pid ) {
            $log->info("Still waiting for the process to finish"); # this should come up every 90 seconds of so
        }
    }

    $log->info("uid $uid: configure script executed"); # this should come up only once, now I get it every 90 seconds

    # do other stuff here after the execution of the configure sub is done
```

Unfortunately I inherited this architecture as it is and cannot change it because there are a lot of services based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to sleep, you can call [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) with a timeout. To implement this reliably, you can employ the [self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) which involves creating a pipe, writing to the pipe in a `SIGCHLD` handler, and making the `select` call wait on the pipe's read handle.

Here's a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Errno qw(EINTR);
use Fcntl qw(F_GETFL F_SETFL O_NONBLOCK);
use Symbol qw(gensym);

sub make_non_blocking {
    my $handle = shift;
    my $flags = fcntl($handle, F_GETFL, 0)
        or die("F_GETFL: $!");
    fcntl($handle, F_SETFL, $flags | O_NONBLOCK)
        or die("F_SETFL: $!");
}

my ($read_handle, $write_handle) = (gensym, gensym);
pipe($read_handle, $write_handle)
    or die("pipe: $!");

make_non_blocking($read_handle);
make_non_blocking($write_handle);

local $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    syswrite($write_handle, "\0", 1);
};

my $pid = fork();
die("fork: $!") if !defined($pid);

if ($pid == 0) {
    sleep(10);
    exit;
}

my $rin = '';
vec($rin, fileno($read_handle), 1) = 1;

while (1) {
    my $nfound = select(my $rout = $rin, undef, undef, 2);
    if ($nfound < 0) {
        # Error. Must restart the select call on EINTR.
        die("select: $!") if $! != EINTR;
    }
    elsif ($nfound == 0) {
        # Timeout.
        print("still running...\n");
    }
    else {
        # Child exited and pipe was written to.
        last;
    }
}

waitpid($pid, 0);

close($read_handle);
close($write_handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run the code and noticed a few things that may be your issue, but without knowing what configure does, I can't be sure. Here's what I found:

1. The child process doesn't `exit` after calling `configure`
2. `waitpid` does not change the value of `$pid`, so $pid is always 0 in the child and always the pid of the child in the parent.

What this means is that the parent is never writing out `"Still waiting for the process to finish"`, the child is writing it out every 90 seconds after it completes it's call to configure.

Additionally, the child should print that message ever 90 seconds forever because it's waiting for pid 0 to send it the CHLD signal which won't happen because it doesn't have a child with pid 0.

I updated your code with a few stubs that does what I think you want (on a slightly tighter timeline because I don't like to wait :) ). My code makes the following assumptions that you may wish to change:

- Log the waiting message every second
- The child always exits with a status value of 0

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);

Log::Log4perl->easy_init();

my ($uid,$mode,$dst_path,$script_dir,$node,$gid) = (0..5);
my $log = get_logger();
$log->info("uid $uid: calling the configure script for operation $mode,on $dst_path");

my $pid   = fork();
die "Could not fork\n" if not defined $pid;

if ( $pid == 0 ) {
    configure( $script_dir, $mode, $node, $uid, $gid); # this also uses a parallel process in its execution, but we don't have a non blocking wait
    exit(0);
}
my $zombie;
while ( ($zombie = waitpid( $pid, WNOHANG ) ) != $pid) {
    $log->info("Still waiting for the process to finish"); # this should come up every 90 seconds of so
    sleep(1);
}

$log->info("uid $uid: configure script executed"); # this should come up only once, now I get it every 90 seconds

# do other stuff here after the execution of the configure sub is done

sub configure {
    sleep 10;
}
```